# Sparticles tag - usefulness?

Tags: discussion, tags

I created a tag today, [sparticles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sparticles), that I thought would be useful to the community. It seemed like there were a decent number of questions that talked specifically about sparticles as opposed to just supersymmetry. Here are some questions I thought would be good with this tag:

- [Sparticles: Relationship to supersymmetry and dark matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17841/sparticles-relationship-to-supersymmetry-and-dark-matter)
- [Why are the third generation superpartners lighter than the other sfermions in MSUGRA](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9258/why-are-the-third-generation-superpartners-lighter-than-the-other-sfermions-in-m)
- [How to find SUSY with near-degenerate masses?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93774/how-to-find-susy-with-near-degenerate-masses)
- [What does the discovery of the Higgs boson mean for SUSY?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/159067/what-does-the-discovery-of-the-higgs-boson-mean-for-susy)
- [To which type of particles gauginos are supposed to couple?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229854/to-which-type-of-particles-gauginos-are-supposed-to-couple)

I think this would be a useful tag to have beyond just a supersymmetry tag. Please tell me what you think of this.

**Bonus:**

Just out of curiosity, I created the tag, but for some reason it now shows that Community created the tag...why would that be?

Comment: Useful indeed!  :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, why not... tags shouldn't be too hard to create for people with enough experience with the site to know when a new one is needed.

However, we do prefer verbose tag names over abbreviated ones, so I think [supersymmetric-particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supersymmetric-particles) or [superpartner-particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superpartner-particles) would be better. The former just fits within the limit of 25 characters for tag names (which is why we don't have [cosmic-microwave-background](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmic-microwave-background)). If people are not opposed to this, one of the mods can rename the tag. You wouldn't need to do anything.

[[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) the tag name has been changed.]

If you're proposing going back and editing existing questions to have the new tag, that's another story. Every edit bumps its question to the top of the front page, so we'd rather not have large batches of edits being done all at once. It's fine to apply the tag to old questions as long as you do only a few at a time (5, perhaps), and make sure to fix any other problems with the questions as you go through them, to minimize the total number of times they need to be edited.

Bonus answer: when you see "created by Community" or the like, I believe what you're looking at is the tag *wiki* edit history, not the history of the tag itself. The tag wiki is an editable information page that is supposed to describe the tag. When a new tag gets created, the system (represented by the Community account) creates a blank tag wiki page to go with it.

Comment: I support the longer tag name (with sparticles as a synonym). Having more verbose, self-explanatory tags is always better (within reason), so long as they fit inside the character limit.

Comment: @DavidZ, understood, the tag was created as sparticles, so if you or another moderator could change the name, that would be great. Do you know why it says it was created by the Community, though?

Comment: Oh, I have an idea, let me edit.

Comment: @DavidZ, great! It works perfectly. I also created a tag wiki/user guidance a little bit ago, so it should be done once that's approved. Thanks for your help!